# Replacing consecutively empty values in a CSV file

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a line of text like:

```
value,value,,,value,value
```

I want the two empty values to be replaced with a different value. Something like:

```
value,value,hello,hello,value,value
```

I'm currently trying something like:

```
sed -e 's/^,/hello,/' -e 's/,$/,hello/' -e 's/,,/,hello,/g'
```

That catches blank values at the beginning, end and the middle. BUT, it doesn't catch two consecutive blank values in a row. How can I update the regular expression patterns so that an indefinite number of consecutive blank values can appear in the middle?

Comment: Sed doesn't support lookaheads or behinds, right.  That makes this harder.  Are any other regex flavors an option in your situation?

Comment: `man sed` says I can use --regexp-extended: use extended regular expressions in the script.

Comment: The solution doesn't have to use `sed` either. Any commonly available tool will do (i.e. installed by default on most distros).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this perl one-liner:

```
echo ',value,,,value,' | perl -pe 's/^(?=,)|(?<=,)(?=,|$)/hello/g'
# hello,value,hello,hello,value,hello
```

Comment: Getting close, but it fails in one scenario I have. The line has four fields and all are empty: `,,,`. Your perl produces `hello,,hello,hello`

Comment: @Steve Prentice: I think I spotted the bug and updated the one-liner. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Glad I could help. Btw, turns out, you don't need captures at all. Check the updated version.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, whats the first backreference for? Ok you edited it... no more references :-) this is magic

Comment: Hehe, page reload helps at times ;) Btw everyone, I just made another tiny change to make it more compact. Last edit this one! (hopefully ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do it with a single substitute command, since Sed only replaces non-overlapped occurrences of your pattern. This ugly hack could work, but requires you to prevent one more character (I choosed ';') in your values :

```
$ echo 'value,value,,,value,value' | sed -r 's/,/,;/g;s/(^|;)(,|$)/\1hello\2/g;s/,;/,/g'
value,value,hello,hello,value,value
```

Comment: +1 Clever. So, you replace every `,` with `,;`, do some magic, and then restore the delimiters. It works, but I'm going to wait on accepting as the answer because I hope there is a less ugly way to do it.

Comment: Well, you could also perform your substitution twice, like this:

    `echo 'value,value,,,value,value' | sed -r 's/(^|,)(,|$)/\1hello\2/g;s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1hello\2/g'`

But that's ugly too :)

Comment: +1 for making it happen with `sed` when the "it doesn't have to be `sed`" part came up after your answer. And some seds will want `-E` rather than `-r` for this.

Comment: I actually like that approach. :) Each one catches every other one.

Answer (score 1):

Other perl one-liners:

```
perl -we '$_=<>; while(s/,,/,hello,/) {}; print;'  value.txt

perl -we 'print join ",", map { $_ || 'hello' } split /,/, <>;' value.txt
```